# If I convert my Ubuntu into Xen hypervizor, will I lose access to the bcache devices?

Tags: 14.04, xen, bcache

I'd like to test Xen a little. For obvious reasons I cannot do it under VirtualBox (or can I?)

As I understand, Xen works by changing the kernel, thus possibly interfering with the custom kernel modules I have, namely with `bcache`.

I'd appreciate an information, whether after doing

```
sudo apt-get install xen-system-amd64 qemu-common qemu-keymaps bridge-utils
```

and then rebooting, will the system load the `bcache` module, as it does without xen?

I have no possibility to back up my 12+ TB RAID array, so I can't test it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xen does not *change* the kernel; it is a hypervisor that sits *below* the kernel.  Grub loads xen, and your normal kernel and xen creates a virtual machine to run that kernel in.  This initial virtual machine has acess to all of the real hardware and ram ( that xen itself isn't using ) on the system, so the kernel operates just as it normally does.  It just has the option to give up some ram and have xen create a new virtual machine and load a new kernel there, while normally only providing the new virtual machine with *emulated* hardware that is is passed back to the initial vm to handle.